# ES6 export object properties separately

Tags: module, ecmascript-6

Say, I have an object like `{foo: 5, bar: 10}` and I wanna export `foo` and `bar` from it separately, then when I do
`import {foo} from './path/to/file';`

I could get `foo` equal to `5`, as if I did
`export const foo = 5;`
`export const bar = 10;`

How can I do it?

Comment: `export const foo = obj.foo; export const bar = obj.bar;`...

Comment: You really *should* do `export const foo = 5; export const bar = 10;`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Exported values need their own top-level variable name. The easiest option might be something like this:

```
const obj = {foo: 5, bar: 10};

export const {foo, bar} = obj;
```

Really though, if the object is already declared in the file, you may be better off declaring the exports with the values directly.

Comment: What if I wanted to export default `obj.foo` only. What would be my alternatives?

Comment: @Telokis I'm not sure what you're describing? `export default obj.foo;` is valid JS.

Comment: Nevermind, the issue is because obj.foo is dynamically generated. Thus, we have to `module.export` it and `eslint` isn't pleased with that. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Telokis Probably best not to use named exports for that then. If it's not a static list, the only time I'd recommend using named exports is if it's a non-static list that could be constructed at build time rather than runtime. If it's dynamically generated based on some runtime source, I'd recommend exporting a single object and using that dynamically instead.

Comment: but how to `export { ...obj }`, i don't want to write key names again.

Comment: @eczn With ES modules, the names being exported have to be known statically, so you cannot pull them from an object.